# Editable Table functionality in R-Mobile Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

I see that datatable works well with Shiny web to have editable cells or rows/columns. They are caught using cell_edit events. But I cant find a similar thing for mobileShiny in f7table. rhandsontable also doesn't support it. Any help on making editable mobileshiny tables?